# How to display a dynamic nested list of checkboxes in Angular template?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, formgroups

I have a list of codes that comes from the API. Each code can be any of the given 6 types. These 6 types are also coming from API.

`types` object[]:

```
0: {typeName: "Type 1", id: 1}
1: {typeName: "Type 2", id: 2}
2: {typeName: "Type 3", id: 3}
3: {typeName: "Type 4", id: 4}
4: {typeName: "Type 5", id: 5}
5: {typeName: "Type 6", id: 6}
```

`allCodes` object[]:

```
0: {codeName: "code1", id: 1, codeTypeId: 1}
1: {codeName: "code2", id: 2, codeTypeId: 5}
2: {codeName: "code3", id: 3, codeTypeId: 2}
3: {codeName: "code4", id: 4, codeTypeId: 3}
4: {codeName: "code5", id: 5, codeTypeId: 4}
5: {codeName: "code6", id: 6, codeTypeId: 4}
6: {codeName: "code7", id: 4, codeTypeId: 3}
```

Here `codeTypeId` is the `id` from `types` object. In the template I want to display a set of checkboxes in the form like:

```
<h3>Type 1</h3>
<input type="checkbox">code1

<h3>Type 2</h3>
<input type="checkbox">code3

<h3>Type 3</h3>
<input type="checkbox">code4
<input type="checkbox">code7

<h3>Type 4</h3>
<input type="checkbox">code5
<input type="checkbox">code6

<h3>Type 5</h3>
<input type="checkbox">code2

<h3>Type 6 </h3>
-- No code added --
```

This is what I have so far:

In my controller:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.codesForm = this.createFormGroup();
    this.addCheckboxes();
}

createFormGroup() {
    return this.fb.group({
        codes: new FormArray([])
    });
}

private addCheckboxes() {

    this.allCodes.forEach((o) => {
        this.isMatch = this.checkedCodes.some((el) => {
            return el.id === o.id;
        });

        (this.codesForm.controls.codes as FormArray).push(new FormControl(this.isMatch));
    });
}
```

In my template:

```
<form [formGroup]="codesForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-1" formArrayName="codes"
        *ngFor="let code of codesForm.controls.codes.controls; let i = index">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{i}}" [formControlName]="i">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{i}}">{{allCodes[i].codeName}}</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

But the above code displays all the checkboxes in one single list, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox">code1
<input type="checkbox">code2
<input type="checkbox">code3
<input type="checkbox">code4
<input type="checkbox">code5
<input type="checkbox">code6
<input type="checkbox">code7
```

How do I group them under their respective types? I tried creating nested `FormArray` controls, but that didn't work.